# Merging Two Datasets on Matched Column in R

Tags: r, database, merge

I'm an R beginner and I'm trying to merge two datasets and having some trouble with losing data. I might be totally off base with what I'm doing.

The first dataset is the Dewey Decimal System and the data looks like this
[image of 10 rows of data from this set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N66i5.png)

I've named this dataset DDC

The next dataset is a list of books ordered during a particular time period.
[image of 10 rows of the book ordering dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSwYu.png)
I've named this dataset DOA

I'm unsure how to include the data not in an image
(Can also provide the .csvs if needed)

I would like to merge the sets based on the first three digits of the call number.

To achieve this I've created a new variable in both sets called  Call_Category2 that takes the first three digits of the call number value to be matched.

`DDC$Call_Category2 = str_pad(DDC$Call_Category, width = 3, side = "left", pad = "0")`

This dataset is just over 1000 rows. It is also padded because the 000 to 099 Dewey Decimal Classifications were dropping their leading 0s

```
DOA_data = transform(DOA_data, Call_Category2 = substr(Call_Category, 1,3))
```

This dataset is about 24000 rows.

I merge the sets and create a new set called DOA_Call

```
DOA_Call = merge(DDC, DOA_data, all.x = TRUE)
```

When I head the data the merge seems to be working properly but 10,000 rows do not get the DOA_Call data added. They just stay in their original state. This is about 40% of my total dataset so it is pretty substantial. My first instinct was that it was only putting DDC rows in once but that would mean I would be missing 23,000 rows which I'm not.

Am I doing something wrong with the merge or could it be an issue with the data not being clean enough?

Let me know if more information is needed!

I don't necessarily need code, pointers on what direction to troubleshoot in would be very helpful!

Comment: The best way to include sample data is with `dput()`. Use `dput(DDC[1:10, ])` to share a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of your `DDC` data - pick a suitable subset that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Probably the rows that don't get data added are rows that don't have a match in `DOA_data`. Take a row that doesn't have a match, and see if you can identify a row in `DOA_data` that should have matched it.

Answer (score -1):

This is my best try with the information you provide. You will need to use:

- functions such as **left_join** from dplyr (see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html)
- the stringt library to handle some variables (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html)
- and some familiarity with the tidyverse.

Please keep in mind that the best way to ask in stackoveflow is by providing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)